# why ldap_connect fatal error in php 5.6.30 version in RHEL 6.9?

Tags: php

---

Hi,

i tried connecting with ldap server using php code.

ERROR:

But it throws an error as fatal error ldap_connect undefined?

Here is the code:

```
<?php

// using ldap bind
$ldaprdn = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']; // ldap rdn or dn
echo $ldaprdn;
$ldappass = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']; // associated password

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("www.analog.com")
or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn)
{
        // binding to ldap server
        $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

        // verify binding
        if ($ldapbind)
        {
                echo "LDAP bind successful...";
        } else {
                echo "LDAP bind failed...";
        }
}

?>
```

THINGS TRIED IN (php.ini) File:

1. I had also uncommented the line extension=php_ldap.dll
2. ALso included the line extension = mod_ldap.so
3. stopped and Started the apache but it not works for me.Still my error continues

Configuration image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what platform/stack you're running PHP on. Depending on the distribution there may be multiple php.ini files. One way to find out is to add the following script:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

then load that in your browser. You should see something like:

[image]

Also if you do have the php_ldap module loaded it should be present on that page.